# Find largest number from user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, infinite-loop

I trying to make a code which print largest and smallest number from user input. I want that user can input the number until there is `ValueError`

I have tried something like this:

```
value = raw_input(">")

largest_so_far = None
smalest_so_far = None

while(value):
    if value > largest_so_far:
        largest_so_far = value
    if ValueError:
        print largest_so_far
```

this code creates infinite loop. So how can I make it finite.

Comment: Please show the actual code you have written. The PS thing is not much helpful in filling the pieces of the code.

Comment: Do you want to do something like; as soon as user enters input you want to show largest and smallest number? OR User will enter all the numbers and you want to show largest and smallest number

Comment: @thefourtheye I have not done much but I have edited question and added full code

Comment: @MaheshGurav I want to that user can input as many as user want till user make inputerror

Comment: @Freddy Then you can create a list of all inputs and just sort the list.First element of your list is the smallest number and last element will be greatest one. You can use bubble sort like thing also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `try` and `except` here.

```
while(True):
    try:
         value = float(raw_input(">"))     # Get the input from user
         if value > largest_so_far:        # Type cast to integer
            largest_so_far = value
    except ValueError as e:                # Handle ValueError
        print largest_so_far
        break                              # Break the infinite loop
```

Comment: You're comparing strings with `>`.

Comment: anyway fail, change to `int(raw_input(">"))`. you forgot about `largest_so_far = value`

Comment: @BhargavRao then you are free to remove brackets `(value)` :D

Comment: @BhargavRao and...possibly `largest_so_far` need to be initialized with `int` type, i.e. 0 :)

Comment: @Reishin only if a user is guaranteed to enter only positive numbers.

Comment: @bereal doesn't matter, comparing with `None` will not give normal results. Coz author doesn't tell anything about range of user input, we should consider that there could be any number

Comment: @Reishin if it's initialized to `0` and a user types e.g. `-1` and `-2`, it will return `0`, while `-1` is expected. So, initialization must be to some sentinel value with an extra condition checking. (BTW, in Python 2, `v > None` for any integer `v`, which is a non-portable hack.)

Comment: @bereal yep, that's right. But `0` was only suggestion. Main think is only about initialization of variable :) P.S. that hack could work differently between 2.x.x, 2.6.X and 2.7.X ...python is a magical language :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Initialize `maxVal` to `-float('inf')` and `minVal` to `float('inf')` then you can update those using `maxVal = max(value, maxVal)` and `minVal = min(value, minVal)`. Problem solved.

Comment: @swenzel Yeah! That is perfect. But I guess, we have to wait for the OP to conform a few things. I will add your comment to my code once the OP does so :)

Comment: works perfectly thanks :) though you can change that **int** to **float**

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
value = raw_input(">")

largest_so_far = None
smalest_so_far = None

while(value):
    if value > largest_so_far:
        largest_so_far = value
    raise ValueError('largest_so_far')
```

Comment: no not working. It shows following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise ValueError('largest_so_far')
ValueError: largest_so_far

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Initialize the largest and smallest values as 'None'  
largest  = None  
smallest = None  

while True:  
    num = input("Enter a number:")  
        if num == "finish": #Type 'finish' to get the output    
    break  
    try:  
        fnum = float(num)  #Convert input to float  

        #Get largest value  
        if largest is None:  
            largest = fnum  
        elif fnum > largest:  
            largest = fnum  

        #Get smallest value  
        elif smallest is None:   
            smallest = fnum  
        elif fnum < smallest:  
            smallest = fnum  

    except: 
        #If the user input is not 'finish' or a number    
        print("Invalid input")   
        continue    


print("Largest value is",largest)  
print("Smallest value is",smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest_so_far = None

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
   try:
        userNumber = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if largest_so_far is None:
            largest_so_far = userNumber

        elif userNumber > largest_so_far:
            largest_so_far = userNumber
   except:
       print('Invalid Input')

print('The largest number you entered is: ', largest_so_far)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to include a description of what your code does.

Answer (score -1):

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter third number: "))

if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
    largest = num1
elif (num2 >= num1) and (num2 >= num3):
    largest = num2
else:
    largest = num3

print("The largest number between", num1, ",", num2, "and", num3, "is", largest)
```